# VDM in Eclipse will not load?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, virtual-device-manager

I have no experience with app development but I was interested in playing around with androids SDK, I downloaded the .zip file and extracted everything onto my desktop. I was attempting to follow the introductory tutorial on androids website, however when it comes time to launch the Virtual Device Manager clicking the button in the toolbar does nothing. Trying to run the app and selecting to add a VDM does not work either.

Navigating directly to the VDM application and attempting to launch it leads to a cmd window opening for a split second. I was able to take a screenshot of the message though which reads:

"Emulator error: you did not specify a virtual device name, and the system directory could not be found."

Prior to attempting the starting tutorial I successfully launched the VDM.
The path to the SDK is set correctly in Eclipse.

I tried re-downloading the SDK to no avail
I am running windows 7, and the latest version of the Android SDK.